# Eclipse - Execute Expression on at Point in Code?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Is it possible to have Eclipse execute an arbitrary expression at a particular point in code when debugging?

The Execute/Display functionality allows you to run arbitrary code in the context of debugging. A breakpoint stops flow.

What I'd like is something like a breakpoint that can be inserted at a particular point in a class, doesn't suspend application flow, but instead executes a snippet of code.

The background is I'm trying to debug some multithreaded code which I can't edit, and I want to do some naive `System.out.println`s to see when various things happen. If I use breakpoints then the flow of the events will be disturbed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha! There's an undocumented feature whereby [conditional breakpoints can execute other code, dubbed 'Printpoints'](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tips/29-types-of-breakpoints-in-eclipse#Printpoint).

[image]

Comment: Here's an example of this great idea being used to not actually break when the breakpoint is hit, but simply log the contents of the `SomeClass` variable to a file. Notice how it returns false at the end of the expression. So now you can simply run your code, and it'll log all the variable values to a file. The code is at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bradparks/adc2a52ff1d1024aa78748ec83b9c97c), and in the next comment as well.

Comment: ```String out;
String outFile = "/tmp/out.txt";

out = SomeClass + "\n";
java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Paths.get(outFile), (out).getBytes(), java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE, java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND); 

return false;```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the "Breakpoint Properties" of a breakpoint to add some code. Hit the "Conditional" Checkbox in the dialog and place your code there.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't even think to try non-conditional code in there!

Comment: Yeah, its kinda nasty, if you ask me. But it helps in your case. I could not recommend it unconditionally, because you interfere with the executing code in a very un-explicit way.